# Trying example Cronjob from Kubnetes with errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to use the example cronjob that is explained through Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). However, when I check it on [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) (a tool to display Kubernetes info), I receive an error upon creating a pod. The only difference between the Kubernetes example and my code is I added a namespace since I do not own the server I am working on. Any help is appreciated. Below is my error and yaml file.

```
Error creating: pods "hello-27928364--1-ftzjb" is forbidden: exceeded quota: test-rq, requested: limits.cpu=16,limits.memory=64Gi,requests.cpu=16,requests.memory=64Gi, used: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=2G,requests.cpu=1,requests.memory=2G, limited: limits.cpu=12,limits.memory=24Gi,requests.cpu=12,requests.memory=24Gi
```

This is my yaml file that I apply.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: test
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: hello
              image: busybox:1.28
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - c
                - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace seems to have a quota configured. Try to configure the resources on your CronJob, for example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: test
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: hello
              image: busybox:1.28
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - c
                - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "64Mi"
                  cpu: "250m"
                limits:
                  memory: "128Mi"
                  cpu: "500m"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Note the **resources:** and it's indentation.

Comment: It seems to have a different problem now, but you are correct. Defining the resources was my issue. I appreciate your help!